# Programatically created labels always shows only the first created one's value

Tags: c#, controls, windows-ce

I create an instance of main project's form from a dll, when reacing the method first time everything is okay, but when I call the method second time it again shows the first created one's values. There is also a datagridview that Works with same logic but not created runtime, it Works fine. I also tried to not create those labels runtime but it didnt make a difference.

dll

```
using (frmBlaBla FRMBLABLAMM = new frmBlaBla())
    {
      Label lbl1 = new Label();
      lbl1.Name = "lbl1";
      lbl1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
      lbl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(345, 15);
      lbl1.Text = "LABEL 1";
      lbl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 30);
      lbl1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
      FRMBLABLAMM.SomePanel.Controls.Add(lbl1);

      Label lbl2 = new Label();
      lbl2.Name = "lbl2";
      lbl2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 20, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
      lbl2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(340, 45);
      lbl2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 45);
      lbl2.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
      lbl2.Text = SomeMethodReturnsString(Param);
      FRMBLABLAMM.SomePanel.Controls.Add(lbl2);

      FRMBLABLAMM.ShowDialog();
    }
```

frmMaster

```
frmBlaBla FRMBLABLA;
```

Comment: set different Locations

Comment: I changed lbl2's x coordinate as 340 and also changed the form's name I created runtime as FRMBLABLAMM coz frmMaster has a global variable as FRMBLABLA but they didn't make any difference, still it looks like it keeps the first created form and shows is again and again when I try to create new one

Comment: edit the question and post your new code.

Comment: the location may not work before shown, how about move the code into Load event?